# macOS Catalina Retain Path Bar in Mounted Folders

Tags: finder, mount, path, dmg

I'm running macOS Catalina, and whenever I download a `*.dmg` and open it, Finder doesn't show a path bar at the bottom.

In older versions of OS X it used to be that the first time I pressed `View -> Show Path Bar` or `⌥⌘P`, it would stay there for all future times I opened a disk image. Now, however, even ejecting and reopening the same disk image has the path bar disappearing.

Is there any way I can make Finder remember the path bar setting? It doesn't seem to be a problem anywhere else that isn't a mounted disk image.

Comment: **DMG** _files_ contain their own settings as to how they will display.  When the **DMG** _file_ opens, just press: **⌥⌘P**

Comment: an addendum to @user3439894's comment - a  .dmg *can* be writable, but probably not if from a 3rd party as an installer 'disk', so your changes will not stick.

Comment: …though of course, the path for a mounted .dmg is always going to be `/disk name` anyway ;))

Comment: @user3439894 yeah, that's what I've been doing. I'm just surprised that despite these settings, on older versions of OS X my Finder settings used to be able to override them.

Comment: How old is "older"? I just tested El Capitan does the same thing.